# Regex to find wildcard imports in Java

Tags: java, regex

Could I get a review on the following regex:

```
^import[\s\S&&[^\*\n]]*?([\*]{1}\;\s*$)
```

All the details:

Years ago a colleague shared a useful little regex for finding wildcard imports in Java, such as the following:

```
import org.example.project.*;
```

But not:

```
import org.example.project.someClass;
```

The critical bit being the `*`. Of course, there's a lot of possible variation in the legal whitespace. Spaces or tabs could be inserted pretty much anywhere.

I couldn't find the regex, or the right search-foo to find one online, so had a stab at writing my own. For the record I am not a natural regexer, I'm sure It could be shorter and simpler.

The regex engine is that in [Jetbrains' IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), which I assume is Java regex.

Comment: This sounds more like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916603/7756856) answer solve your actual problem? (you might have to use ctrl+alt+o or ctrl+alt+L to force cleaning up imports after changing the settings).

Comment: @Imus Thanks, yes, that solves the wildcard problem in Intellij, but this question was about improving my feeble regex skills - it's just coincidence that I want a regex to help find another problem in Java code (for which I don't need to open a codereview.se question).